# Create model based on UV projected texture

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, shrinkwrap

I'm not sure how to phrase the title...
Basically I'm working on a Spider-Man model to import into the new Marvel's Spiderman PC game,and I'm trying to create the raised webbing.
I have the model and a texture indicating where the webbing should be, what I need is a way to somehow create the webbing mesh around the model only where that texture is.
[image: Example of webbing mask]

I tried vectorizing the texture, and importing it to then shrink-wrap it around the model, but that didn't work.
Now I'm trying to use geometry nodes to extrude the webbing, but I have to increase the poly count too much for that to work and since I intend to import the model into a game, increasinng the poly count that much wouldn't work
[image]

Isn't there a way to create a mesh from that texture that automatically wraps around the model.
Or does anybody have a suggestion to creating this webbing that doesn't imply manually modeling each thread by hand?

Comment: if you don't want to increase the face count, why don't you keep an image instead and use a bump map to fake the 3D relief?

Comment: I don't have a problem increasing the poly count, of course to add new geometry the poly count has to increase, but the methods I've used require me to drastically increase the poly count, in a way the game engine wouldn't be able to handle it. The model already has a normal map (not visible on these pictures) but I want to replace it for a 3d model of the webbing. I was hoping there was a way to "cut" the geometry on the edge between the black and white parts of the textures, then extrude only the black parts